# I want to add a user to a Group based on name form a CVS file

Tags: windows, scripting, powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

I have the following code that can make a user however when I write the group in the CSV file the user is not added to said group.
 I am able to run this right on the server.
The group is in a sub-group of a much larger group. so I am also not sure how to inform Powershell I want a group of a group.

this is the path would this work?
BILOMNI.BILPROMETRIC.ROOT/EasyServe_OU/EasyServeChannel_OU/Channel_CenterUsers_OU

I also have the group unique name
RequestingAccess_CenterUsers_GG

```
        $computer = $ENV:COMPUTERNAME;
        $users = Import-Csv "C:\Users.csv";

    Foreach ($user in $users)
    {
    #for ($i=0; $i -le 2000; $i++)
    #{
        # Grab required info
        $userName = $user.User
        $objOu = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"
        $Group = $user.Group

        # Create user
        $objUser = $objOU.Create("User", $userName + $i)
        $objUser.setpassword($user.password)
        $objUser.SetInfo()

        # Find target group and add the user to it
        $de = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$Group,Group"
        $de.add([ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$userName")

       # }
    }

    The following exception occurred while retrieving member "add": "An invalid dn syntax has been specified.
"
At C:\Users\dennis.hayden\Desktop\makingbilusers.ps1:20 char:12

+     $de.add <<<< ([ADSI]"LDAP://$computer/$userName")

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember
```

Below is the CSV file I am use:

```
User,Group,password

Masstestuser,RequestingAccess_CenterUsers_GG,P@ssWord
```

Comment: You are really working in 'Workgroup' or you are working in domain ?

Comment: I believe a domain the group has a unique name thought so I am not sure why I can't just use that.

Comment: If you are working on a domain, you are on Active-Directory, so it would be better to replace "WinNT://" by "LDAP://"

Comment: I just male the change but still the user is not added to the group I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Try to modify a bit your cod, like I show in my answer. If it's not workin, can you give a sample of your csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change all your `Wint://` by `LDAP://` and modify a bit your code like the following :

```
# Find target group and add the user to it
$de = [ADSI]"LDAP://$computer/$Group,Group"
$user=[ADSI]"LDAP://$computer/$userName"
$de.add($user.Path)

# Commit
$de.setinfo()
```

Comment: If I change this line the code breaks and it does not even add a user. $objOu = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"

Comment: You still use Winnt ! Give a bit of you csv, I will have a look tonight.

Comment: What i dont understand is that if i say a simple group say Guests the script is still not working. I have tryed $computer+"/"+ "Guests". so that it uses a group path why is this? so hard?? CSV is added to the end of OP